# Delete a coredata record(row) of a tableview on Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, delete-row

I am a bit stuck here. Tried many posts and ideas here from Stack, but could not get it to delete content from the table view. Neither deleting a record from COREDATA or a simple testing array. Apart from that the code works fine, lists data and displays in the tableview.

This is the error I am getting:

> 2015-07-09 21:49:24.881 PlaygroundApp[36985:1319445] *** Assertion
>   failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:],
>   /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3347.44/UITableView.m:1623 2015-07-09
>   21:49:24.889 PlaygroundApp[36985:1319445] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreData

class MyTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    var cellCount = Int()
    var selectedCell = Int()
    var totalResults = Int()

    // THIS VARIABLE IS INITIALISED BY COREDATA FETCHREQUEST THEN USED TO POPULATE CELLS
    var recipients = [Float]()

    //THIS IS JUST A TEST VAR TO TEST THE TABLE VIEW DELETE
    var recipientsTeste = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // FETCH COREDATA
        var appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
        var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "ConcreteEntity")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        var fecthResults = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!


        //PRODUCE ARRAY FROM COREDATA
        if fecthResults.count > 0 {
            var saydir = fecthResults.count - 1
            for (var i=0; i < fecthResults.count; i++) {
                let match = fecthResults[i] as! NSManagedObject
                var tela = match.valueForKey("costAt") as! Float
                println(tela)

                recipients.append(tela)
            }

        } else {

        }

        //DEFINE # OF RECORDS AT COREDATA
        totalResults = fecthResults.count

    }

    // NUMBER OF CELLS BASED ON # OF RECORDS AT COREDATA
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

        return totalResults
    }

    // TRANSFER COREDATA RECORDS TO CELLS
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        // LABEL CELL
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(recipientsTeste[indexPath.row])"

        return cell

    }

    // IDENTIFY CLICKED CELLS
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        selectedCell = indexPath.row
        println(selectedCell)

        // DEFINE AN ACTION LATER TO USE THE SELECTED ROW AND CLOSE VIEW
        if indexPath.row == 0 {

            println("I clicked ZERO")
            navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
        }
    }

    // ENABLE EDIT
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    // EDIT CELL

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        //// I GET THIS INFO PRINTED CORRECTLY. IT CALLS THE METHOD FINE.
        //   println("delete indexPath \(indexPath.row)and \(recipients[indexPath.row])")

        //****************** THIS IS THE BIT THAT DOESNT WORK **********************

        switch editingStyle {
        case .Delete:

            var appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
            var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "ConcreteEntity")
            request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
            var fecthResults = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!

            context.deleteObject(fecthResults[indexPath.row] as! NSManagedObject)
            fecthResults.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            context.save(nil)

            tableView.reloadData()
            // remove the deleted item from the `UITableView`
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)

        default:
            return

        }
        // *************************************************************************
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

}
```

Comment: update your "totalResults" variable with fecthResults.count  after removeAtIndex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reloading the table, which will remove the rows you are trying to delete, then you try and delete the rows again. Remove the call to `tableView.reloadData()`.

```
tableView.reloadData() // Delete this line

// remove the deleted item from the `UITableView`
tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
```

Edit: You should look into [NSFetchedResultsController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/) its made for this kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks for you tip mate. I did some research and found a really good tutorial. Not on NSFetchedResultsController specifically. But they it is explained I finally understood what each bit does.

http://jamesonquave.com/blog/core-data-in-swift-tutorial-part-1/